# How to execute makecab/f command from notepad?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

How can I run a command that is located in a folder using a text file. Here is the command

```
C:\Program Files\GAPS\XML Forms\CSurvey\temp>makecab/f directories.txt
```

currently I am able to run upto this path "C:\Program Files\GAPS\XML Forms\CSurvey\temp" using notepad by using the following as a notepad content

```
cmd /k "cd C:\Program Files\GAPS\XML Forms\CSurvey\temp"
```

But i'm not able  to run the `makecab/f directories.txt` from notepad. how to modify the notepad content so that the `makecab/f directories.txt` will execute automatically without manually typing the command in run window?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to be able to run the above command using a text file?

That does not make much sense, but maybe due to your English level, I can try to answer your question

1. Open a new notepad text file.
2. Type the command you want to run:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\GAPS\XML Forms\CSurvey\temp>makecab/f "C:\Program Files\GAPS\XML Forms\CSurvey\temp\directories.txt"
   ```
3. Notice that you need to specify full path for `directories.txt` because since you will run this command from somewhere else, you would need to make sure the path is correct.
4. Save the file as `SomeFileName.bat` notice that you must save it with `.bat` not `.txt` otherwise, the file will not be executable. Also, make sure Windows is not hiding known extensions to avoid having your file named: `YourFileName.bat.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of solving your problem.

If you want the command window to remain open after finishing the job, then change this line:

```
cmd /k "cd C:\Program Files\GAPS\XML Forms\CSurvey\temp"
```

to this one:

```
cmd /k "cd C:\Program Files\GAPS\XML Forms\CSurvey\temp & makecab/f directories.txt"
```

Alternatively, though, you could have the command window close automatically upon completing the batch script. In that case replace your command with these two lines:

```
cd C:\Program Files\GAPS\XML Forms\CSurvey\temp
makecab/f directories.txt
```

Note the absence of `cmd /k`. The command window will automatically open when you start the script and it will stay open while the script is executing.